# How do I read a text file line by line?

Tags: php

suppose I do have a text file with these lines

name: Mathew
Age : 32
Country : USA
Location : California
bla bla bla....

What I want is I want a php code which can read this file and display result to a webpage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this code (untested):

```
$fp = fopen('filename.php');
while (!eof($fp)) {
    $line = fgets($fp);
    // Add code to display the values how you want
    echo $line."<br>";
}
fclose($fp);
```

That will loop through the file line by line.  Each line will be assigned to the $line variable, and then you can manipulate and display the values how you would like.

Answer (score 2):

file() function reads a file into an array where one element represents a string in the file

Answer (score 1):

Display the actual text or remove the `name:`, etc?

Use the `file()` function ([tutorial?](http://www.tizag.com/phpT/files.php)) to read the file in and then echo out / process each line.